# div disappearing in mobile layout?

Tags: css, html

I am currently working on css using media queries to change the layout of a site for mobile devices. Everything is working fine apart from when I test on my mobile phone, the div with id #slideshow is disappearing, like it's css is set to display:none. I've looked at my code and been playing around with it for an hour now and whatever I try I can't seem to get it to display! Is there anything you guys can see that could cause this?

html looks like this:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial­‐scale=1.0, width=device­‐width"/>
    <title>****</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    function windowH() {
    var wH = $(window).height();

    $('.sideBar, .slideshow').css({height: wH});
    }

    windowH();
    </script>
    <div id="page"><!--Whole page container-->
        <div id="sidebar"><!--Side bar container-->
            <div id="logo">
                <img id="logoimg" src="Images/logo2.png">
            </div>
        <div id="nav">
            <div class="linkdiv" id="homelink">
                 <a class="link" href="<!--Link to home-->"><p>Home</p></a>
            </div>
            <div class="linkdiv" id="aboutlink">
                <a class="link" href="<!--Link to about-->"><p>About</p></a>
            </div>
            <div class="linkdiv" id="gallerylink">
                <a class="link" href="<!--Link to gallery-->"><p>Gallery</p></a>
            </div>
            <div class="linkdiv" id="priceslink">
                <a class="link" href="<!--Link to prices-->"><p>Prices</p></a>
            </div>
            <div class="linkdiv" id="reviewslink">
                <a class="link" href="<!--Link to reviews-->"><p>Reviews</p></a>
            </div>
            <div class="linkdiv" id="contactlink">
                <a class="link" href="contact.html"><p>Contact</p></a>
            </div>
            <div class="linkdiv" id="clientslink">
                <a class="link" href="<!--Link to clients-->"><p>Clients</p></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="icons"><!--Icons container-->
            <span class="mediaicon" id="twitter">
                <a class="iconlink" href="http://www.twitter.com/">
                    <img class="icon" src="Images/ticon2.png"></a>
            </span>
            <span class="mediaicon" id="facebook">
                <a class="iconlink" href="http://www.facebook.com/">
                    <img class="icon" src="Images/ficon2.png"></a>
            </span>
            <span class="mediaicon" id="pintrest">
                <a class="iconlink" href="http://www.pintrest.com/">
                    <img class="icon" src="Images/picon2.png"></a>
            </span>
            <span class="mediaicon" id="wordpress">
                <a class="iconlink" href="http://****.wordpress.com">
                    <img class="icon" src="Images/wicon2.png"></a>
            </span>
       </div>
    </div>
    <div id="moblogo">
        <img id="moblogoimg" src="Images/logo2.png">
    </div>
    <div class="mobilemenu">
        <a class="link" href="#priceslink"><p>Menu</p></a>
    </div>
    <div id="slideshow"><!--Image slideshow container-->
    </div>
    <div id="mobnav">
        <div class="linkdiv" id="homelink">
           <a class="link" href="<!--Link to home-->"><p>Home</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="linkdiv" id="aboutlink">
            <a class="link" href="<!--Link to about-->"><p>About</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="linkdiv" id="gallerylink">
            <a class="link" href="<!--Link to gallery-->"><p>Gallery</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="linkdiv" id="priceslink">
            <a class="link" href="<!--Link to prices-->"><p>Prices</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="linkdiv" id="reviewslink">
            <a class="link" href="<!--Link to reviews-->"><p>Reviews</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="linkdiv" id="contactlink">
            <a class="link" href="contact.html"><p>Contact</p></a>
        </div>
        <div class="linkdiv" id="clientslink">
            <a class="link" href="<!--Link to clients-->"><p>Clients</p></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mobicons"><!--Icons container-->
        <span class="mediaicon" id="twitter">
            <a class="iconlink" href="http://www.twitter.com/">
                <img class="icon" src="Images/ticon2.png"></a>
        </span>
        <span class="mediaicon" id="facebook">
            <a class="iconlink" href="http://www.facebook.com/">
                <img class="icon" src="Images/ficon2.png"></a>
        </span>
        <span class="mediaicon" id="pintrest">
            <a class="iconlink" href="http://www.pintrest.com/">
                <img class="icon" src="Images/picon2.png"></a>
        </span>
        <span class="mediaicon" id="wordpress">
            <a class="iconlink" href="http://****.wordpress.com">
                <img class="icon" src="Images/wicon2.png"></a>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my css is as follows:

```
    html
{
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

body
{
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}

p
{
display: inline;
}

#page 
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

#sidebar
{
float: left;
width: 20%;
height: 100%;
padding-bottom: 10;
margin: 0;
background-image: url(Images/back2.jpg);
}

#slideshow
{
float: right;
width: 80%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-image: url(Images/sl1.jpg);
animation: slideshow 60s;
animation-iteration-count: infinite;
-webkit-animation: slideshow 60s;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
background-size: cover;
}

#logoimg
{
width: 80%;
margin-top: 7%;
margin-left: 10%;
margin-right: 10%;
}

#moblogo
{
display: none;
}

.linkdiv
{
font-family: canter;
font-size: 2em;
text-align: center;
padding-top: 5%;
padding-bottom: 2%;
color: rgba(255,255,255,1.00); 
}

.mobilemenu
{
display: none;
}

a:link
{
color: rgba(109,110,112,1.00);
text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited
{
color: rgba(109,110,112,1.00);
text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover
{
color: rgba(167,167,168,1.00);
text-decoration: none;
}

a:active
{
color: rgba(109,110,112,1.00);
text-decoration: none;
}

.icon
{
width: 15%;
}

#icons
{
margin-left: 27%;
margin-top: 10%;
padding: 0;
}

#mobicons
{
display: none;
}

#mobnav
{
display: none;
}

    @media only screen 
and (max-device-width: 640px)
and (orientation: portrait) 
{
html
    {
    height: auto;
    }

body
    {
    height: auto;
    }

#page
    {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    }

#sidebar
    {
    display: none;
    }

#moblogo
    {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(Images/mobbg1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    position: static;
    display: block;
    }

#slideshow
    {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
    position: static;
    display: block;
    }

#moblogoimg
    {
    width: 70%;
    margin-top: 0.2em;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-right: 15%;
    }

.linkdiv
    {
    font-size: 0.5em;
    padding-top: 0.2em;
    padding-bottom: 0.2em;
    }

#mobnav
    {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    text-align: center;
    }

.mobilemenu
    {
    font-family: canter;
    font-size: 0.5em;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    display: block;
    background-image: url(Images/iconbgipadport.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    position: static;
    }

#mobicons
    {
    display: block;
    position: static;
    }
}

    @keyframes slideshow
    {
    0%          {background-image: url(Images/sl1.jpg);}
    8.3%        {background-image: url(Images/sl2.jpg);}
    16.7%       {background-image: url(Images/sl3.jpg);}
    25%         {background-image: url(Images/sl4.jpg);}
    33.3%       {background-image: url(Images/sl5.jpg);}
    41.7%       {background-image: url(Images/sl6.jpg);}
    50%         {background-image: url(Images/sl7.jpg);}
    58.3%       {background-image: url(Images/sl8.jpg);}
    66.7%       {background-image: url(Images/sl9.jpg);}
    75%         {background-image: url(Images/sl10.jpg);}
    83.3%       {background-image: url(Images/sl11.jpg);}
    91.7%       {background-image: url(Images/sl12.jpg);}
    100%        {background-image: url(Images/sl1.jpg);}
    }

@-webkit-keyframes slideshow
{
    0%          {background-image: url(Images/sl1.jpg);}
    8.3%        {background-image: url(Images/sl2.jpg);}
    16.7%       {background-image: url(Images/sl3.jpg);}
    25%         {background-image: url(Images/sl4.jpg);}
    33.3%       {background-image: url(Images/sl5.jpg);}
    41.7%       {background-image: url(Images/sl6.jpg);}
    50%         {background-image: url(Images/sl7.jpg);}
    58.3%       {background-image: url(Images/sl8.jpg);}
    66.7%       {background-image: url(Images/sl9.jpg);}
    75%         {background-image: url(Images/sl10.jpg);}
    83.3%       {background-image: url(Images/sl11.jpg);}
    91.7%       {background-image: url(Images/sl12.jpg);}
    100%        {background-image: url(Images/sl1.jpg);}
    }
```

Any help or criticism greatly appreciated.

Comment: What type of mobile device you testing on?

Comment: What's a jsfiddle? Currently testing on an iPhone 5 and iPhone 4s both running iOS 7.0.3.

Comment: This is a http://jsfiddle.net/77fYL/. Usually it doesn't include the whole shebang, but just the necessary parts to reproduce the relevant behaviour.

Comment: Okay so here's a jsfiddle I made http://jsfiddle.net/seabrook132/y5Yhp/, but it's not showing the relevant problem because the problem only happens when my media query comes into play for mobile devices. Can you use a jsfiddle to reproduce that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK I figured the problem out.
Your styles works fine, all percentage are ok and stuff. The problem is the media query.

When you do your media query, you set `#page` height to `height:50%`.
In order to set the height of an element in %, it's parent needs to have a fixed height OR a % it self ( but in this case the parent of the parent needs to have an height, and so on)

Your initial CSS was ok with that because `html` , `body` , `#page` were set to `height:100%`, so you have been free to set `#slideshow` to `height:100%`.

**BUT (and that's the point)**: In your media query you set `html` , `body` , `#page` to `height:auto`. Doing this, your `#slideshow` can't do any percent of the height. How can it do a percentage of nothing? The result is that your `#slideshow` just disappears from screen.

A possible solution colud be to set a fixed height to `html` , `body` , `#page` or just leave them to `height:100%` (which I suggest) so you will be free to set `#slideshow` height to `height:50%` as you wished.

Comment: Thanks for this Kevin. I follow what you've said and yes you're right it can't therefore calculate the percentage. I see how your solution would work as well, by setting the height to 100% on those elements, however I still want the page to scroll vertically because the content becomes fairly hard to read if it's all shown at once.

Comment: I've just figured out a second solution though. The div #slideshow has no content in it because all the images are in the @keyframes css for the animation and this is also contributing to it having no height, because the div has no html content inside it. To solve this I have applied padding-top: 50% to the div #slideshow and it now shows up again and I can still scroll the page too.